# how to untar tgz files distinctly

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have number of .tgz files with the exact same name, i want to untar them all in one directory with uniq names. My preference would be append the name of the folder the .tgz came from,

```
original location= /folder1/folder2/2015/04/08/something1.tgz
original location= /folder1/folder2/2015/04/09/something2.tgz
```

after the untar, i would like them decompressed as below

```
target_folder= 20150408_something1
target_folder= 20150409_something2
```

Comment: check tar's manpage. especially the `-C` flag.

Comment: I have tried the man page but i was unable to see anything

Answer (score 0):

`something1.tar.gz` and `something2.tar.gz` don't have the same name. I assume you mean they contain the same toplevel folder/files?

In which case (and assuming your folder hierarchy is consistent in the path to all the tarballs) you should be able to use something like this.

```
for arc in /folder1/folder2/2015/04/08/something1.tgz /folder1/folder2/2015/04/09/something2.tgz; do
    # Get just the filename of the archive.
    fname=$(basename "$arc")
    # Strip off the extension from the filename.
    fname=${fname%.*}

    # Get just the last three directory components.
    dname=$(awk -F / '{print $(NF-3)$(NF-2)$(NF-1)}' <<<"$arc")

    mkdir "${dname}_$fname" || { ret=$?; echo "Could not create directory ${dname}_$fname."; exit $ret; }
    tar -xvf "$arc" -C "${dname}_$fname"
done
```

Comment: @neil If this solved your problem then you should accept it. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for how this works in general on this site.